# Correct way to avoid browser cache with GruntJS

Tags: javascript, html, caching, gruntjs, http-caching

I'm trying to find a good way to release a new version of a single page javascript app without asking clients to refresh their page or clear caches when a new version is deployed

I'm currently revving images / css / js files in my javascript app, so it contains references like `scripts/671df76d.main.js` and that's great.

So in my webapp v0.1 index.html I have something like this:

```
<script data-main=“scripts/d7ba3e7b.main” src=“bower_components/requirejs/require.js”></script>
```

while in a new v0.2 version I have  this:

```
<script data-main=“scripts/671df76d.main” src=“bower_components/requirejs/require.js”></script>
```

I also experimented with meta tags that might influence caching.

```
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

But I never found a good solution. Sometimes the updates are shown without requiring a manual refresh from the user, sometimes old content is still being shown. The only way to get the user to see the new content is to ask him to refresh the page.

As users are always visiting the webapp through the index.html, I noticed that sometimes the latest version is picked up (v0.2 with `671df76d.main`), but other times after deployment the browser still loads up a previous version.

I'm just wondering how I can guarantee a browser won't have cached my index.html with an old `scripts/d7ba3e7b.main.js`

It makes sense that the browser can have a cached version the `index.html` , so it would still refer to old/stale revved javascript sources (obviously something you don't want).

In that sense the fact that you rev your resources is useless.

Am I correct in saying that simply revving up resources inside the `index.html` is not sufficient and that some additional stuff is needed

- html meta tags
- htaccess files
- webserver configs

What would be a proper way to do this ? Again, the goal being to allow users to see your new version without having to ask them to refresh / clear cache.